# Successful PHP login does only appear after reloading the page

Tags: php, session, authentication

I've a little problem with my login script. Everything works fine, but when I submit my form, the page reloads & does not show that im logged in. Now, when I reload the page again from myself, it does show that I'm logged in (The echo test). I'm really not getting behind the problem. Everything is in my index.php, I know there are other ways to do it, but this is for a very special application.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
  ?>
  <!-- Some HTML here -->
  <?php
  // if isset POST (...) & SQL Script here
  if ($user !== false && password_verify($passwort, $user['passwort'])) {
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $user['id'];
    echo "test";
  } else {
    $errorMessage = "Die eingegebenen Login-Daten sind nicht korrekt.<br>Bitte versuchen Sie es erneut.<br><br>";
  }

  if(isset($errorMessage)) {
    echo $errorMessage;
  }
  ?>
  <section>
    <form method="post">
      <input type="text" name="loginname" placeholder="Benutzername oder E-Mail" autofocus maxlength="64" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" required><br>
      <input type="password" name="passwort" placeholder="Passwort" maxlength="64" autocorrect="off" required><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Anmelden"><br><br>
    </form>
  </section>
  <?php
} else if(isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
  $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
  echo "Hallo User: ".$userid;
}
?>
```

Okay so I think I found my mistake.
When I load the page the first time -> No userid is set.
When I submit the form -> No userid is set.
When the Script now comes to `if(isset())` it does set a userid.
Now a userid is set, but logically it now ignores the else if statement.
Has anyone a nice workaround? Because I would really like to stay on the main page. (Also no AJAX)

Comment: The 'second page' thing is standard in php sessions.... http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: Even if you don't like it, javascript with AJAX is the cleanest way to do this on 'one page'.

Comment: @CFPSupport The second page thing may be a problem when using `setcookie()` and expecting to see changes reflected into `$_COOKIE`, but I don't think there's such problem with sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I've found a solution to my problem.
If Login is set -> Show no Form
If Login is set and correct -> Show the User Panel
If Login is set, but incorrect -> Show Form
If Login is not set -> Show Form
To round things up, simply include all the other stuff. (In this case login.php)

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
  if(isset($_POST["loginname"]) && isset($_POST["passwort"])) {

    //  SQL Script here

    if ($user !== false && password_verify($passwort, $user['passwort'])) {
      $showFormular = false;
      $_SESSION['userid'] = $user['id'];
    } else {
      $showFormular = true;
      $errorMessage = "Die eingegebenen Login-Daten sind nicht korrekt.<br>Bitte versuchen Sie es erneut.<br><br>";
    }
  } else {
    $showFormular = true;
  }

} else if(isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
  $showFormular = false;
}

if ($showFormular) {
  include "login.php";
} else {
  $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
  echo "Hallo User: ".$userid;
}
?>
```